# Matlab: Plot line on a particular figure

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Is there a way to specify that a line should be plotted on a particular figure.
I am running a code, which at various points draws stuff on multiple figures. Everythings works fine if i do not interact with matlab while the code is running.

The problem is, I switch between matlab figures (manually to check results) while matlab is running which sometimes causes matlab to plot stuff on wrong figure.
I am calling "figure(fig_handle)" just before doing the plotting but still matlab sometimes draws stuff on wrong figure. Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Do you have a hold (hold on or hold all) for the current figure prior to plotting? Otherwise it should plot into a new figure I think.

Comment: If you're using `plot`, you can explicitly add an `axes` as the first parameter for plotting. Such as: `fig_handle=figure; ax=gca; plot(ax,xline,yline);`. If you're using `line` to plot, you have to set `gca(ax);` before it, but it might not be foolproof if you're jumping around figures.

Comment: I am using "hold on". Matlab plots everything but some lines are plotted on wrong figures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without [specifying a specific axes object or handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#btzppjx-1), Matlab outputs the graphics to the current axes, which can be [affected by user interaction](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html#moreabout):

> User interaction can change the current axes. If you need to access a specific axes, store the axes handle in your program code when you create the axes and use this handle instead of `gca`.

So, in this case, I'd suggest something like this:

```
figure(1);
x = linspace(0,2*pi);
plot(x,sin(x));
ax1 = gca;
ax1.NextPlot = 'add';
figure(2);
plot(ax1,x,cos(x));
```

This will add the plots to the specified axis regardless of figure order or user-induced focus.

Comment: It would probably be better to just store the axes handles on generation and use them explicitly so the behavior is consistent rather on relying on `gca`

Comment: @excaza That's what I did ... ?

Comment: Thanks. The code below seems to fix my problem. *figure* does not create any axes so i have to check that correct axes is being selected.
<code>
h_fig    = figure(1);
hold(gca, 'on');%create axes
h_ax     = h_fig.CurrentAxes;
while ~isequal(gca, h_ax)% if h_ax is empty
    figure(h_fig)
    h_ax = h_fig.CurrentAxes;
    hold(h_ax, 'on')
end
plot(h_ax, 1:10, 1:10)
</code>

Comment: I mean call `axes` explicitly and not rely on `gca`. This is what you quoted from the documentation and then didn't do.

Comment: @excaza I see what you mean.

Comment: @Saad Per what @excaza said, you can explicitly create an axes (and parent figure) using the [`axes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html) function if you don't need the figure handle.